# Demonstrate $3+9+27+\cdots +3^{n}=(\frac{3}{2})\left ( 3^{n}-1 \right )$

Tags: proof-writing

Good day! I have this for this one, but I cannot get it. What am I doing wrong?

$3+9+27+\cdots +3^{n}=(\cfrac{3}{2})\left ( 3^{n}-1 \right )$

$3^{1}=\left ( \cfrac{3}{2} \right )\left ( 3^{1} -1\right )$

$3=\left ( \cfrac{3}{2} \right )\left ( 2\right )$

$3 = 3$

Then the second part:

$3+9+27+\cdots +3^{k}=(\cfrac{3}{2})\left ( 3^{k}-1 \right )$

$3+9+27+\cdots +3^{k}+3^{k+1}=(\cfrac{3}{2})\left ( 3^{k+1}-1 \right )$

In the left side I have:

$3+9+27+\cdots +3^{k}+3^{k+1}=(3+9+27+\cdots +3^{k})+3^{k+1}$

Substituting in:

$3+9+27+\cdots +3^{k}=(\cfrac{3}{2})\left ( 3^{k+1}-1 \right )$

$=(\cfrac{3}{2})\left ( 3^{k+1}-1 \right )+3^{k+1}$

Comment: In the first step your mistake is that $3$ is already the first term of the sequence.

Comment: I was also confused about that..  In the formula it says that you it goes 3+9+27+---+3^n ... Like, there are two times 3, but one is to the "n". It said so in my papers... But I don't know if that's actually correct. I was also wondering about that..

Comment: You have to consider the powers of 3 up to the n-th power. If $n=1$ you take only the first power of 3.

Comment: @lynneerwell are u german?

Comment: @Desperado Ahh, I see! Thank you!

Comment: @vitamin d  no, not German. Thank you for the comment of the 3!

Comment: "In the formula it says that you it goes 3+9+27+---+3^n ... Like, there are two times 3, but one is to the "n"."  Right.  $3 + 9 + 27 + .... + 3^n = 3^1 + 3^2 + 3^3 + .... + 3^n$.

So the first would be $3^1 = \frac 32(3^1-1)$ which is true and the next would be $3^1 + 3^2 = \frac 32(3^2-1)$ which is equiv to $3+9 = \frac 32\cdot 8$ which is equiv to $12= 12$.  etc

Comment: @fleablood I see! Thank you so much for clarifying me that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$3+9+27+\cdots +3^{n}=$

$3(1 + 3 + 9 + ... + 3^{n-1}) =$

$\frac 32\cdot [2\times (1 + 3 + 9 + ... + 3^{n-1})]$

So we now have to prove that $3^n-1 = 2(1 + 3 + 9 + ... + 3^{n-1})$

There's a trick and an insight and as a hint I will ask you to think about how on earth the $2$ could be related to $3$.

> $2 = (3-1)$

So we have to prove:

> $(3-1)(1+3+9 + .... + 3^{n-1}) = 3^n-1$.

Which try it out.....

> $(3-1)(1+3+9 + .... + 3^{n-1}) = 3^n-1$
>  $3(1+3+9 + .... + 3^{n-1}) - 1(1+3+9 + .... + 3^{n-1}) =$
>  $(3 + 9 + 27 + ...... + 3^n) - (1 + 3+ 9 + ..... + 3^{n-1}) = $
>  $(3+9+27 + 81 + ..... + 3^{n-2}+3^{n-1} + 3^n) - (1 + 3 + 9 + 27+81 + .... +3^{n-2}+3^{n-1}) =\require{cancel}$
>  $(\cancel 3+\cancel 9+\cancel{27} + \cancel{81} + ..... + \cancel{3^{n-2}}+\cancel{3^{n-1}} + 3^n) - (1 + \cancel 3+\cancel 9+\cancel{27} + \cancel{81} + ..... + \cancel{3^{n-2}}+\cancel{3^{n-1}}) =$
>  $3^n -1$.

Comment: Thank you very much, @fleablood, for taking the time to showing me how it can be done with hints and everything. You sound like an amazing person, and you have really good teaching skills. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fact that $3^i=\frac{3^{i+1}-3^i}{2}$ whenever $i\in\Bbb N$
$$
\begin{aligned}\sum_{i=1}^n 3^i&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n 3^{i+1}-3^i\\&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n 3^{i+1}-\sum_{i=1}^n3^i\right)\\&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{i=2}^{n+1} 3^{i}-\sum_{i=1}^n3^i\right)\\&=\frac{1}{2}\left(3^{n+1}+\sum_{i=2}^{n} 3^{i}-\left[3+\sum_{i=2}^n3^i\right]\right)\\&=\frac{1}{2}(3^{n+1}-3)\\&=\frac{3}{2}(3^{n}-1)
\end{aligned}$$

In general, we have that $a^i=\frac{a^{i+1}-a^i}{a-1}$, and, therefore
$$\sum_{i=1}^n a^i=\frac{1}{a-1}\sum_{i=1}^n a^{i+1}-a^i=\frac{1}{a-1}(a^{n+1}-a)=\frac{a(a^{n}-1)}{a-1}$$

Comment: Thank you very much, Patricio! For all of that. I will really think about it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you were looking for.

$$(3/2)(3^k - 1) + 3^{k+1} = (3/2)(3^k - 1 + 2\cdot 3^k)
= (3/2)(3\cdot 3^k - 1) =(3/2)(3^{k+1} - 1)$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

You should know from high school that the sum of consecutive terms of a geometric series with common ratio $q$ is given by the formula:
$$a_m+a_{m+1}+\dots +a_n=\frac{a_{n+1}-a_m}{q-1}\qquad (n>m).$$

Comment: I suspect the the purpose of this exercise *is* to establish that result for the first time.  For all we know the OP is in high school *now*. (Although not all of us learn this in high school).